# what is the use of passing null and number in JSON.stringify() function

Tags: javascript, json

```js
{
  JSON.stringify(
    {
      selectedFlatRows: selectedFlatRows.map((row) => row.original),
    },
    null,
    2
  )
}
```

In the above function, what is the use of passing null and 2 in the JSON.stringify function?

in this [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-EFSkq4AaI&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwgWTSrDiwmUsl4ZvipOw9Cz&index=14), it has been done like this

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify? Compare the output with and without the extra parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Second argument of JSON.stringify is the replacer.
This means if this value is null or not provided,
all properties of the object are included in the resulting JSON string.